# ServletException java.lang.StackOverflowError thrown sometimes with multiple doGet() calls - Weblogic 10

Tags: java, stack-overflow, weblogic-10.x

We have an application running on weblogic 10 server. While navigating this application, sometimes randomly the users are getting the following exception trace.
The code is based on servlet/jsp framework. All codes are going to the COntroler.java, then BAsisServlet.java and then the corresponding Servlet.
We have not been able to identify a particular flow causing this error. It is very random. In local system we are never able to replicate the same. 
In some other posts I saw that the "/*" can cause stack overflow issues, but what is confusing me is that why is it occurring only sometimes. Any input regarding the issue is appreciated.

```
                    <[weblogic.servle
                    t.internal.WebAppServletContext@375e95f - appName: 'ebasis', name: '/', context-
                    path: ''] Root cause of ServletException.
                    java.lang.StackOverflowError
                            at weblogic.utils.StringUtils.getString(StringUtils.java:556)
                            at weblogic.utils.http.BytesToString.newString(BytesToString.java:14)
                            at weblogic.utils.http.BytesToString.newString(BytesToString.java:10)
                            at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestHeaders.getHeaderValue(RequestHeader
                    s.java:82)
                    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestHeaders.getHeader(RequestHeaders.java:41)
                            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.getHeader(Unknown Source)
                            at com.ba.basis.servlet.BasisServlet.isLoggedOnUserValid(BasisServlet.java:1749)
                            at com.ba.basis.servlet.Controller.doPost(Controller.java:293)
                            at com.ba.basis.servlet.Controller.doGet(Controller.java:72)
                            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
                            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
                            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:226)
                            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:124)
                            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:283)
                            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
                            at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:525)
                           at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:261)
                        at com.ba.basis.servlet.Controller.doPost(Controller.java:658)
                        at com.ba.basis.servlet.Controller.doGet(Controller.java:72)
                        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
                        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
                        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:226)
                        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:124)
                        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:283)
                        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
                        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:525)
                        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:261)
                        at com.ba.basis.servlet.Controller.doPost(Controller.java:658)
                        at com.ba.basis.servlet.Controller.doGet(Controller.java:72)
```

As you can see above, the forward method is being called recursively.

The web.xml is like :

```
                    <servlet-mapping>
                    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
                    <url-pattern>/ebasis/*</url-pattern>
                </servlet-mapping>
                    <servlet-mapping>
                            <servlet-name>Search</servlet-name>
                            <url-pattern>/Search/*</url-pattern>
                    </servlet-mapping>
```

BasisServlet.java

```
protected void processHttpRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException {
                // set up the no-cache part of the response
                /*System.out.println("#####1 |" + request.getRequestURI());
                System.out.println("#####2 |" + request.getPathInfo());
                System.out.println("#####3 |" + request.getPathTranslated());
                System.out.println("#####4 |" + request.getServletPath());
                System.out.println("#####5 |" + request.getRequestURL());*/

                response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
                response.setIntHeader("Expires", 0);

                DisplayValueBean displayValueBean = (DisplayValueBean)request.getAttribute(ServletDefines.DISPLAYVALUEBEAN);
            //  HttpSession session;
                String methodIdentifier = "doPost";
                String methodToExecute = new String();
                com.ba.basis.util.NavState nav;
                //Find the method required to be called from the user's NavState
                //object held in the session
                try {
                    //session = request.getSession(true);
                //  session = request.getSession(false);

                    //nav = (com.ba.basis.util.NavState) session.getAttribute(ServletDefines.NAVIGATION_STATE);
                    nav = (com.ba.basis.util.NavState) displayValueBean.getNavState();
                    methodToExecute = nav.getServletMethodName();

                } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                    log(classIdentifier, methodIdentifier,
                            "eBASIS-2-100004", null, npe, request, response);
                }
                /* Call required method by Introspection */
                try {
                    Class c = this.getClass();
                    //Create a class of correct type to inspect for method names
                    //Create array of parameter types consistent with method signature.
                    //All methods called in this way have 'request' and 'response'
                    // passed in.
                    Class paramtypes[];
                    java.lang.reflect.Method m;
                    Object arglist[];
                    if( (methodToExecute != null) && methodToExecute.equalsIgnoreCase("removeSystemFilter")){               
                        paramtypes = new Class[3];
                        paramtypes[0] = Class
                                .forName("javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest");
                        paramtypes[1] = Class
                                .forName("javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse");
                        paramtypes[2] = Class
                                .forName("com.ba.basis.servlet.DisplayValueBean");

                        m = c.getDeclaredMethod(methodToExecute,
                                paramtypes);
                        //Create array of arguments to be passed into method
                        arglist = new Object[3];
                        arglist[0] = request;
                        arglist[1] = response;
                        arglist[2] = displayValueBean;
                        request.setAttribute(ServletDefines.DISPLAYVALUEBEAN, displayValueBean);
                    }else{

                     paramtypes = new Class[2];
                    paramtypes[0] = Class
                            .forName("javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest");
                    paramtypes[1] = Class
                            .forName("javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse");
                    //Find named method with defined signature
                     m = c.getDeclaredMethod(methodToExecute,
                            paramtypes);
                    //Create array of arguments to be passed into method
                     arglist = new Object[2];
        //          System.out.println("Before entering Line 1167 in Basis Servlet TM :: "+Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()+" FM:: "+Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
                    arglist[0] = request;
        //          System.out.println("After entering Line 1167 in Basis Servlet TM :: "+Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()+" FM:: "+Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
                    arglist[1] = response;
        //          System.out.println("After entering Line 1168 in Basis Servlet TM :: "+Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()+" FM:: "+Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
                    request.setAttribute(ServletDefines.DISPLAYVALUEBEAN, displayValueBean);
                    }
                    //long beforeMethodCall = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    //Invoke method on this instance of the class, passing in desired
                    // arguments
                    m.invoke(this, arglist);
                    //long afterMethodCall = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //          Log.write("Time to execute method :: "+m+" of class :: "+c+" within BasisServlet's processHttpRequest is :: "+(afterMethodCall - beforeMethodCall)+" ms");
                } catch (java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException ite) {
                    log(classIdentifier, methodIdentifier,
                            "eBASIS-3-100005", null, ite, request, response);
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
                    log(classIdentifier, methodIdentifier,
                            "eBASIS-2-100006", "Method called= " + methodToExecute,
                            nsme, request, response);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log(classIdentifier, methodIdentifier,
                            "eBASIS-2-100007", null, e, request, response);
                }
            }
```

Controller.java

```
protected void processHttpRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // set up the no-cache part of the response

            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            response.setIntHeader("Expires", 0);

            DisplayValueBean displayValueBean = (DisplayValueBean)request.getAttribute(ServletDefines.DISPLAYVALUEBEAN);
        //  HttpSession session;
            String methodIdentifier = "doPost";
            String methodToExecute = new String();
            com.ba.basis.util.NavState nav;
            //Find the method required to be called from the user's NavState
            //object held in the session
            try {
                session.getAttribute(ServletDefines.NAVIGATION_STATE);
                nav = (com.ba.basis.util.NavState) displayValueBean.getNavState();
                methodToExecute = nav.getServletMethodName();

            } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                log(classIdentifier, methodIdentifier,
                        "eBASIS-2-100004", null, npe, request, response);
            }
            /* Call required method by Introspection */
            try {
                Class c = this.getClass();
                //Create a class of correct type to inspect for method names
                //Create array of parameter types consistent with method signature.
                //All methods called in this way have 'request' and 'response'
                // passed in.
                Class paramtypes[];
                java.lang.reflect.Method m;
                Object arglist[];
                if( (methodToExecute != null) && methodToExecute.equalsIgnoreCase("removeSystemFilter")){               
                    paramtypes = new Class[3];
                    paramtypes[0] = Class
                            .forName("javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest");
                    paramtypes[1] = Class
                            .forName("javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse");
                    paramtypes[2] = Class
                            .forName("com.ba.basis.servlet.DisplayValueBean");

                    m = c.getDeclaredMethod(methodToExecute,
                            paramtypes);
//Create array of arguments to be passed into method
                    arglist = new Object[3];
                    arglist[0] = request;
                    arglist[1] = response;
                    arglist[2] = displayValueBean;
                    request.setAttribute(ServletDefines.DISPLAYVALUEBEAN, displayValueBean);
                }else{

                 paramtypes = new Class[2];
                paramtypes[0] = Class
                        .forName("javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest");
                paramtypes[1] = Class
                        .forName("javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse");
                //Find named method with defined signature
                 m = c.getDeclaredMethod(methodToExecute,
                        paramtypes);
                //Create array of arguments to be passed into method
                 arglist = new Object[2];
    //          System.out.println("Before entering Line 1167 in Basis Servlet TM :: "+Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()+" FM:: "+Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
                arglist[0] = request;
    //          System.out.println("After entering Line 1167 in Basis Servlet TM :: "+Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()+" FM:: "+Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
                arglist[1] = response;
    //          System.out.println("After entering Line 1168 in Basis Servlet TM :: "+Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()+" FM:: "+Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
                request.setAttribute(ServletDefines.DISPLAYVALUEBEAN, displayValueBean);
                }
                //long beforeMethodCall = System.currentTimeMillis();
                //Invoke method on this instance of the class, passing in desired
                // arguments
                m.invoke(this, arglist);
                //long afterMethodCall = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //          Log.write("Time to execute method :: "+m+" of class :: "+c+" within BasisServlet's processHttpRequest is :: "+(afterMethodCall - beforeMethodCall)+" ms");
            } catch (java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException ite) {
                log(classIdentifier, methodIdentifier,
                        "eBASIS-3-100005", null, ite, request, response);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
                log(classIdentifier, methodIdentifier,
                        "eBASIS-2-100006", "Method called= " + methodToExecute,
                        nsme, request, response);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log(classIdentifier, methodIdentifier,
                        "eBASIS-2-100007", null, e, request, response);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you post your `BasisServlet.java` and `Controller.java`?

Comment: I am posting the methods which are accessed while hitting url.

Comment: COntent updated with BasisServlet and Controller methods

Answer (score 0):

Finding causes for such runtime exceptions like StackOverflowException is hard to investigate without access to the code and knowing of user input. Especially if an error randomly appears. And especially in case of dynamic nature of methods calling as you posted.

I don't believe, that specifying "/*"-pattern in deployment decriptor can cause such kind of random issues.

I can advice only to check (what actually stack trace says) a business logic (reason of calling doPost() from doGet() and reason and point of redirection) in:

```
at com.ba.basis.servlet.Controller.doPost(Controller.java:658)
at com.ba.basis.servlet.Controller.doGet(Controller.java:72)
```

And maybe this method is a good candidate to check too:

```
at com.ba.basis.servlet.BasisServlet.isLoggedOnUserValid(BasisServlet.java:1749)
```

BTW, it would be cleaner to change your reflection-relevant code to:

```
paramtypes = new Class[] {HttpServletRequest.class, HttpServletResponse.class, DisplayValueBean.class};
m = c.getDeclaredMethod(methodToExecute, paramtypes);
//Create array of arguments to be passed into method
arglist = new Object[] {request, response, displayValueBean};
```